# Como quitar diseño LAYOUT en una vista?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buen día, alguno de uds sabra como puedo quitar el diseño layout en una vista? MVC? Actualmente intente hacer esto...

```
@{Layout = ""} y tambien esto @{Layout = null}
```

Funciona muy bien se quita el diseño, pero no me permite hacer conexiones a la base de datos... no realiza una consulta que tengo con Ajax... vuelvo a poner el layout y funciona normal.. alguien sabra del porque? soy principiante en esto jeje gracias.

Comment: Esto te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&list=PL-_pdwtmHN2TcXVCoDc0qSqzwRFgJarO_&index=13&t=1s Un workshop de 4 horas sobre ASp Net MVC con Entity Framework. Los mismos conceptos aplican a Asp net core. Saludos.

Comment: lo mas probable es por que en tu código falta el ; al final de la instrucción ```
@{ Layout = null;
}
```
saludos